# How to fix scaling problems in "plot_ly" function from the package plotly

Tags: r

I am trying to draw contour plots through plot_ly function from the package "plotly".But the scaling of x and y in the outcomes is different from what I have defined.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a reproducible example et what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem with scaling. but the next problem is that for one of the contour plots, the values of z are complex! so how can I use plotly for complex values of z?